# Wifi not working properly in HP bs145tu

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome on my laptop and the Wifi module was not working as soon as I booted into the system, so I followed these steps

[image: Wifi Setup Steps for hp bs145tu]

But after doing the setup my wifi was still loading and "No networks" were showing.

[image: No Wifi networks shown]

It just spins up forever and no wifi networks are found, how can I resetup the wifi and make it working.

```
sahil@sahil-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: You are trying to install drivers for all kinds of devices, but you didn't find out wihci device is installed. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added the required logs.

Comment: If you just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with GNOME, you might want to start again with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (which has 5 years of support life, not 3 of 16.04 GNOME).  Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*)   https://ubuntugnome.org/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to view support status for your actual status, but only the server, desktop (ie. Unity 7 or default desktop) and Kylin are still supported for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: The driver looks to be properly installed. Maybe you need to set `ant_sel` parameter.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've tried that but it's still showing the same problem.

Comment: How did you try it. Run `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1` Also try with `ant_sel=2`if 1 doesn't help.

Comment: I've did both, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then install a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: Okay, I'm installing 18.04 then